# Можно ли в БЭМ верстке подключать reset.css и применять символ * для сброса всех отступов?

Tags: html, css, бэм

Вычитал, что при верстке по БЭМ нельзя применять такие общие стили, как * { margin: 0; padding: 0; } и что нельзя подключать файл со сбрасыванием стилей, типа отмены подчеркивания ссылок, маркировки li в ul списках итд. Это действительно так?

Answer (score 0):

Да, это так. Вот что говорит документация к БЭМ

> На блоки не должны влиять CSS-правила, созданные для всей страницы. Это нарушает их независимость и затрудняет повторное использование.
> Общий сброс стилей по сути реализуется с помощью глобальных CSS-правил, которые в большинстве случаев пишутся к селекторам на тег, что нежелательно делать в БЭМ-проекте.

[FAQ](https://ru.bem.info/methodology/faq/#%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9-reset)

Но ничего не мешает сбрасывать стили внутри каждого БЭМ блока.

Comment: то есть получается в каждом блоке, где есть ссылки и лишки надо указывать text-decoration: none и list-style: none и это нормально?

Comment: @Dresosr, да, всё верно. По итогу, будет немного больше кода, цена модульности. 
Зато потом можно "выдрать" этот блок, без страха потерять наследованные стили или сбросы стилей.

Answer (score 0):

reset.css вообще нельзя использовать это крайне неэффективный подход от которого только больше проблем.

А вот normalize.css неплохая практика, но в том случае если вы не полагаетесь на normalize, а описываете каждый блок полноценно, а normalize выступает в качестве базовой заглушки.

Объясню подробнее. normalize приводит к единому стилю дефолтные значения, которые каждый браузер назначает по своему и в случае, если вы не описали элемент, при использовании normalize вы получите адекватно форматированный контент, а в случае с reset.css это будет сплошной  слитый в единую кашу текст, без видимых заголовков, параграфов, списков и т.д.. А еще с reset.css форматирование контента из админки приводит к полному фиаско, потому что многие кто его используют не понимают, что сайт это не сплошная статика.

Comment: А можно тогда в файле глобальных стилей задать * { box-sizing: border-box; } ? И можно ли так же и там же задать для всех  ссылок и li свойства, чтобы они не были маркированными и не подчеркивались? Ведь все равно нет сайтов, где лишки и ссылки  выглядели со стилистикой по умолчанию

Comment: @Dresosr вообще-то полно сайтов где стилистика идет по умолчанию, оформление описания товаров в магазинах, темы блогов и прочее зачастую делается визуальным редактором и когда вы вместо маркированного списка со всеми отступами, делаете такие обнуления, вы попросту все ломаете. Основная задача каждый блок описать полноценно без зависимости от reset и normalize. Вы можете реализовать базовые стили ссылкам, чтобы придать им единый формат или спискам придать иной вид, но по умолчанию каждый элемент должен быть таким каким он задуман. Обнуления это плохо, глобальные правила, это очень плохо.

Comment: даже box-sizing: border-box?

Comment: @Dresosr Тем более box-sizing это очень опасное свойство. Если вы добавите его глобально и будете полагаться на него не учитывая в своих блоках, то при переносе в другой проект, где не будет глобально добавлен такой же box-sizing, ваши блоки будут работать некорректно, а если вы решите его добавить, то можете сломать то что уже реализовано, таким образом проект попадет в замкнутый круг, в котором надо будет исправлять либо ваши блоки, либо блоки проекта.. Одна из основных идей БЭМ это возможность переиспользования и если вы правильно опишите блок, то глобальные стили вам не понадобятся.

Comment: то есть получается в каждом блоке, где есть ссылки и лишки надо указывать  text-decoration: none и list-style: none и это нормально?

Comment: @Dresosr Да. Это нормально и это удобно. Еще раз: "Каждый блок должен быть описан полностью. Никакие внешние правила не должны влиять не него."